# How to send the XML file using JMeter to IBM MQ?

Tags: jmeter, websphere, ibm-mq

I am new to IBM MQ and I have followed the steps mentioned in [JMETER IBM MQ Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)and successfully connected to the IBM MQ. In this link, I could see the string mentioned in the line

`def payload = String.format("JMeter...IBM MQ...test message no. %09d!", rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE))`

is reflecting the IBM MQ.

Now, my question here is, how to send the content/xml file to the IBM MQ.

1. Fetching the file using the below code in JSR223 Sampler,

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
   String fileContents = new File('./test.xml').getText('UTF-8');
   vars.put("content",fileContents);
   ```
2. Code snippet used in JSR223 Sampler to send the xml,

```
    def payload =  vars.get("content");
    def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)})
    def start = Instant.now()
    producer.send(msg)
```

By doing this, *Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script4.groovy: 15: Unexpected input: '"' @ line 15, column 34.
def payload = "* is observed.

Kindly help me how can I achieve sending xml to IBM MQ using JMETER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo:

```
def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)})
                                         ^here
```

just change it to

```
def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)
```

and it should start working as expected.

Just in case:

- [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)
- [Write and run your first IBM MQ JMS application](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-develop-mq-jms/)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, thanks for the help. After correcting the braces the request was successful.

Now, assume xml is having >1000lines. Is it right to do `vars.put("content", fileContents)` and fetch it though `vars.get("content");` 

As I don't see the XML file is reflecting in the queue. So, please help.

Note: I am on Jmeter 5.4.1

Comment: [By default IBMMQ message limit is 4MB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/EAI3/EAI3_EAIMQSeriesTrans8.html), no matter how many "lines" you have. Maximum message size is 100 MB. Both values fit into JMeter Variables without any problem. You can look into [JMeter log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) and search for something like `MQRC_MSG_TOO_BIG_FOR_Q `